# Notification does't work when there are two tabs of one page open

Tags: asp.net-mvc, notifications, signalr

I'm using notification on my MVC web application along with SignalR. I'm calling client function in a certain page from the server. The problem is that no notification pops up when that page is open in two browser tabs at the same time. I should mention that it do works fine when the page is only open in one tab.

I've noticed that if I place an alert right before the line where notification object is created, both tabs receive notifications and that is what I expect. Thanks in advance.

```
$(function () {
    var notificationHub = $.connection.notificationHub;
    $.connection.hub.start();
    notificationHub.client.sendMessage = function (content) {
        setTimeout(notifyMe(content), 10);
    };
});

function notifyMe(message) {
    if (!("Notification" in window)) {
        alert("This browser does not support system notifications");
    }
    else if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
        var notification = new Notification(message);            
    }
    else if (Notification.permission !== 'denied') {
        Notification.requestPermission(function (permission) {
            // If the user accepts, let's create a notification
            if (permission === "granted") {
                var notification = new Notification(message);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Update:**
Here is the scenario in which the notification creation code is preceded by an alert which makes it to work as expected:

```
    function notifyMe(message, system) {
        if (!("Notification" in window)) {
            alert("This browser does not support system notifications");
        }
        else if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
            alert('hit');
            var notification = new Notification(system, {
                body: message,
                tag: (Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)).toString(),
                icon: 'Content/Images/logo.png',
                dir: 'rtl',
                background: '#ff0000'
            });

        }
        else if (Notification.permission !== 'denied') {
            alert('hit');
            Notification.requestPermission(function (permission) {
                if (permission === "granted") {
                    var notification = new Notification(message)
                }
            });
        }
    }

$(function () {
    var notificationHub = $.connection.notificationHub;
    $.connection.hub.start();
    notificationHub.client.sendMessage = function (content, system) {
        setTimeout(notifyMe(content, system), 10);
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The Problem could be in your signalr initialization codes.
I am assuming the `var notificationHub` is a globla object and you have placed this doe in a master page.

Then you need to check if `notificationHub` is null before initializing it. Just change your code like this:

```
$(function () {
    if(notificationHub === undefined || notificationHub === null){
       var notificationHub = $.connection.notificationHub;
       $.connection.hub.start();
       notificationHub.client.sendMessage = function (content) {
           setTimeout(notifyMe(content), 10);
       };
    }
});
```

**Update:**

As you have confirmed that signalr is working properly (i.e. alert message is working in both tabs) then try the followings for the `Notification` object:

```
var notification = new Notification('Test', {
    body : message,
    tag : 'notify-tag-name', //Make this a random number
    icon : 'icon.png'
});
```

Note that if the value of the *tag* property are the same in both browser tabs then Notification will only displayed once even if many browser tabs are open. In that case you can but a random number in the tag name to make it sure they are different across tabs.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I changed my code the way you asked but the problem persists. I'm confident that initialization is just OK and there must be something wrong about the notification creation itself. As I mentioned before if I put an alert right before notification creation, it works the way It is supposed to.

Comment: What type of object `Notification` is? Is it a third party library or a custom one?

Comment: No, It's not a third party library. it's builtin feature. you may have noticed that on many websites when they ask your permission to send you notifications. Here is the documentation page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notifications_API/Using_the_Notifications_API

Comment: Ok, its the standard browser library. I have updated the answer. Give it a try?

Comment: Sorry for late reply @Rahatur, the random tag didn't work either. The problem is, no notification displayed in two open tab scenario. It only works when Notification creation line preceded by an alert.

Comment: @Metti So it means it is not working for multiple tabs! I am assuming you are constructing the `Notification` object the way I had shown? Did you try on different browser? I am wondering if it is a browser specific issue.

Comment: I tried browsers like Chrome, Firefox and Edge. I created Notification object the way you'd showed but the result was the same. I'm still wondering why it do works in multiple tabs when preceded by an alert.

Comment: That is interesting! Can you share the full code with alert that works?

Comment: Can you remove the timeout function `setTimeout(notifyMe(content), 10);` and just call the `notifyMe`?

Comment: Initially there was no timeout function, I added it later to see if it could help solving the problem.